# OData Query to Only Return State Changes from Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, powerbi, odata

I have an OData Query that I am using to pull data into PowerBI that I am trying to make more efficient.  I am doing a report from Azure DevOps and pulling data in from the WorkItemRevisions resource.  Currently, I am pulling all the data for a Work Item and then filtering in PowerBI to only get when the State has changed.  I would like to move this filtering to the Odata query so that I can minimize the data that I am pulling into the report.

Currently, I have a query like the following (simplified example used for this question)

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/{Organization}/{Project}/_odata/v3.0-preview/WorkItemRevisions?
$select=Revision,WorkItemId,WorkItemType,Title,State,ChangedDate,LeadTimeDays,ParentWorkItemId
```

How can this be updated so that only Revisions where the State has changed (from New to Active, Active to Done, etc) are returned?

Answer (score 0):

> How can this be updated so that only Revisions where the State has changed (from New to Active, Active to Done, etc) are returned?

I am afraid that OData Query could not perfectly achieve what we need.

There is a feature `Revisions/any(r:r/state eq '{state}')` to filter the work item has a set state in the past.

For example:

```
https://analytics.dev.azure.com/<Organization>/<Project>/_odata/v2.0//WorkItems?
  $filter=State eq 'Closed' and Revisions/any(r:r/State eq 'Active')
```

This query is similar to a Work Item query that uses the **Was Ever** operator.

As I said, this may not be a perfect solution. That because it can only filter whether the work item **has ever had a specified states**, but cannot accurately determine the states of the work item must be from `New` to `Active`, `Active` to `Done`. If we change the state of the workitem from `Active` to `Resolved`, then change it from `Resolved` to `Closed`. Then this work item will appear in the query results.

**In addition**, even if you use the UI query, we cannot accurately query the result of the work item status changing from A to B. To achieve this goal, we need to use REST API.

So, we could use the feature `Revisions/any(r:r/state eq '{state}')` to reduce the data pulled into the report to a certain extent.

Comment: From your response, my questions was not as clear as I thought.  I'm not looking to try and pull data only for specific state changes ( A to B), but only looking for the data when a state has changed.  So if there 5 changes on a record.
1 State - New
2. State - Active
3. State - Active + Some other change
4. State - Closed
5. State - Closed + Some other Change

I only want to pull back data from records 1, 2 & 4

Sorry for delay in response, as this was not a pressing issue, but is now due to the time in loading the report due to the amount of data.

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query to achieve what you want.

```
 /_odata/v4.0-preview/WorkItemRevisions?&$apply=filter(((WorkItem/WorkItemType
 eq 'Bug' or WorkItem/WorkItemType eq 'Product Backlog Item') and 
 ((WorkItem/ChangedDate ge 2022-10-05Z and WorkItem/ChangedDate le
 2022-11-04Z) or (WorkItem/CreatedDate ge 2022-10-05Z and
 WorkItem/CreatedDate le 2022-11-04Z))))/groupby((WorkItemId,State),
 aggregate(ChangedDate with min as MinChangedDate))
```

To filter the group by data you need to encapsulate it under $apply as it is shown above.

Above URL will return all states and their changed dates for Bug and PBI Work Item types which are added or updated with a given date range.

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

if you are able to use Analytics Views instead of OData, there is a dedicated field available in Analytics Views *Fields* setting called "State Changed Date"